# T-SQL Like statement behaves differently when using a string literal vs using a variable for the search text

Tags: sql

I have found that the T-SQL LIKE statement behaves differently when using a variable to hold the search text - please advise if there is something I doing wrong.

```
select 'True' where 'A242' like 'A2%';
True

create table temptable (code char(10),searchtext char(10));
insert into temptable ('A242','A2%');
select * from temptable where code like searchtext;
(no rows)

update temptable 
set searchtext = 'A2%%' 
where code = 'A242';

select * 
from temptable 
where code like searchtext;
A242
```

It seems like when using a variable the % match pattern doesn't match to any length string but only to the length of the search text.

Comment: Try VARCHAR, as CHAR pads with spaces. :) Nice on Monday morning. BTW in Stackoverflow when indenting with 4 spaces a code block is created, like `select ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `char(10)` columns, rather than `varchar(10)` columns, so your data is stored padded with spaces so that the values are exactly 10 characters long.

It should therefore be clear why the matching doesn’t occur as you expect: "A242*<6 spaces>*" does not match "A2%*<7 spaces>*", but does match "A2%%*<6 spaces>*".